# How to display a USB drive path along with serial number using Linux shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I am new to linux/ shell programming. This shell script is require for of my AIR application. Using Linux shell script, I want to display the USB Drive along with their serial number like follow

> /media/USBDisk:ABC1241GBD|/media/IBALL:ABC1241GTEB

Answer (score 1):

```
DEV=/dev/sda
SERIAL=$(udevadm info --query=property --name=$DEV | grep ^ID_SERIAL=)
SERIAL=${SERIAL#ID_SERIAL=}
echo $DEV $SERIAL
```